# Why both CMD and entrypoint defined in some images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-run, docker-entrypoint

I have seen some images that based on the `inspect` have both `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` set.
What is the idea of this? What use cases are served when both are set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

```
CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
```

this means that CMD can be used as a list of parametres to the entrypoint.

### UPD 1

the idea here is that you can specify the entrypoint (binary to run at start) and then have CMD parameters to this entrypoint which can be overridden.

### UPD 2

Here is an example:

```
cat Dockerfile
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT ["ls"]
CMD ["etc"]
```

now that if you build the image and run it without any arguments, it will product the list with the content of `etc` folder

```
$ docker run lister
group
hostname
hosts
localtime
mtab
network
passwd
resolv.conf
shadow
```

if you do specify the arguments though, you can override the CMD and list the content of a different folder

```
$ docker run lister var
spool
www
```

so the executable stays the same in both cases, while the CMD in the Dockerfile is defining the default argument to this binary. Then we can override when we run the container.

Comment: I don't understand. I could override the entrypoint anyway. Why define both then?

Comment: you could, or you could not override it, keep it and only work with arguments

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Comment: Ah I see now. So it is only when the `CMD` does not have an executable defined right?

Comment: correct, this is only for when the executable comes from the entrypoint and cmd defines the default arguments to this executable.

Comment: It wasn't easy to understand with the `cmd` and `other cmd` pseudo examples. Could you update with some actual commands so that it is clearer? I'll accept the answer

Comment: Hope this new example is a bit cleaner.

Comment: I have experienced that --flags specified in `CMD` to the executable added as `ENTRYPOINT` returns `ERROR: failed to solve: dockerfile parse error on line 15: unknown flag: `